# BaseRouterStoreState is missing the properties from type 'ActionReducerMap<State, Action>'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx, angular8

I keep getting the following error:

> Error:(11, 18) TS2739: Type '{ router: (state: RouterReducerState, action: Action) => RouterReducerState; }' is missing the following
>   properties from type 'ActionReducerMap': user, error

I've looked at examples like: https://github.com/starjumper30/toh-ngrx8/blob/3a8d61d8423af8543de8a30aed16ee941ffcea0b/src/app/reducers/index.ts where it seems to be set up in a similar way and works fine.

This is my code:

```
import { Action, ActionReducer, ActionReducerMap, MetaReducer } from '@ngrx/store';
import { State } from '../modules/auth/auth.reducer';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import * as fromRouter from "@ngrx/router-store";
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export interface State {
  router: fromRouter.RouterReducerState<any>;
}
export const ROOT_REDUCERS = new InjectionToken<ActionReducerMap<State, Action>>('Root reducers token', {
  factory: () => ({
    router: fromRouter.routerReducer
  })
});

export function logger(reducer: ActionReducer<State>): ActionReducer<State> {
  return (state: State, action: any): any => {
    const result = reducer(state, action);
    console.groupCollapsed(action.type);
    console.log('prev state', state);
    console.log('action', action);
    console.log('next state', result);
    console.groupEnd();
    return result;
  };
}

export const metaReducers: MetaReducer<State>[] = !environment.production
  ? [logger]
  : [];
```

What is the cause of this error and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you my have error at this line

```
import { State } from '../modules/auth/auth.reducer';
```

So you can remove it because there is already an State interface state define within your file

also here I dont use `State`

```
return (state: State, action: any): any => { // remove State here
```

My full working code will be like this

```
import {
  ActionReducer,
  ActionReducerMap,
  MetaReducer,
  Action
} from "@ngrx/store";
import { environment } from "../../../environments/environment";
import * as fromRouter from "@ngrx/router-store";
import { InjectionToken } from "@angular/core";

export interface State {
  router: fromRouter.RouterReducerState<any>;
}

export const ROOT_REDUCERS = new InjectionToken<
  ActionReducerMap<State, Action>
>("Root reducers token", {
  factory: () => ({
    router: fromRouter.routerReducer
  })
});

export function logger(reducer: ActionReducer<State>): ActionReducer<State> {
  return (state, action) => {
    const result = reducer(state, action);
    console.groupCollapsed(action.type);
    console.log("prev state", state);
    console.log("action", action);
    console.log("next state", result);
    console.groupEnd();

    return result;
  };
}

export const metaReducers: MetaReducer<State>[] = !environment.production
  ? [logger]
  : [];
```